# Odoo module Website Builder and eCommerce not installing?

Tags: python, odoo-11

I have worked with website builder and ecommerce but for starting a clean project I uninstall all Modules ( including website builder and ecommerce ). Now in odoo not installing this two module. 
Getting those errors

```
Odoo Server Error - Validation Error
The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: website - website]
```

Comment: Try to check this feed: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/21905

Comment: I have solved that thanks